# How windows side by side (WinSxS) mechanism works?

Tags: windows, security, internals, winsxs

If I'm not wrong, if an application specifies dependency in its manifest, Windows loader will load the specified version of the DLL from `C:\Windows\WinSxS\xxx\` folder.

While I was researching on `C:\Windows\System32\dccw.exe` - which is the "Display Color Calibration" app on windows, I saw this weird behavior:

```
Application manifest has only one dependency - "Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
 which is basically the - comctl32.dll
```

[image]

However when you run `dccw.exe`, it loads two DLL from WinSXS folder; `comctl32.dll` as expected and also `GdiPlus.dll`.

[image]

Isn't a dependency for `GdiPlus.dll` should have been present in the manifest. Or did I not understand how WinSxS works correctly?

Comment: I think it is a security thing, gdiplus is redirected because there is a bugfix version. Where or how, I don't know.

Comment: WinSxS has more than one use.  The files in c:\windows\system32, like gdiplus.dll, are not actually files, they are hard links to winsxs.  Makes life easy for Windows Update and the System File Checker utility.  You need the manifest entry to choose the desired version of comctl32.dll, no such choice is needed for gdiplus.dll.  
 https://serverfault.com/questions/319134/how-do-i-view-a-files-hard-links-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required that all dependencies be specified in the application manifest. You can add some but leave out others.

As Hans mentioned in a comment, `gdiplus` under `WinSxS` is a hardlink to the same file in `system32`:

```
    > C:\Windows\system32>fsutil.exe hardlink list GdiPlus.dll

    \Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus.systemcopy_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.
         19041.1645_none_5b73408eab60fd9c\GdiPlus.dll
    \Windows\System32\GdiPlus.dll
```

So functionally it doesn't matter which 'copy' of that file gets loaded.

---

As to WHY the process seems to load from `WinSxS` ... the two hard links are [indistinguishable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110720-00/?p=10103). There is [nothing documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications) to suggest that WinSxS would be used as a DLL search location by default.

This may just be how Process Monitor chooses to report the file's location (?). If you compare to other tools like (archaic) Dependency Walker or [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) you get different results. One shows the `WinSxS` location, the other shows `system32`:

[image]

[image]